# (c# + sql ) HttpClient to authenticate login process

Tags: c#, winforms, httpclient, asynchttpclient

I am new to c# and i am working on application so the client can

- Login
- Sign-up (the registration form has full-name, address and phone number, the  data will be saved into SQL using rest ).

The client can login with only his full-name using winForm.

My question is how can i use HttpClient in my client side to authenticate his login in ?

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://newappliaction.azurewebsites.net/api/Form");
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Edited**

> Its login to my winForm not to my website. The idea is that the client will login to my winForm using his fullname the Httpclient will send a request to the website to check if the same fullname exists in the database(azure sql) if yes then the user logs in

Comment: First, you need to have login/authn provider, are you using openId-connect or any standard? In case you want the user login to your website as shown in your code `mywebsite.com` then use `WebBroswer` component. Please edit the question and add clear details about the login provider.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Thanks for your comment. Its login to my winForm not to my website. The idea is that the client will login to my winForm using his fullname the Httpclient will send a request to the website to check if the same fullname exists in the database(azure sql) if yes then the user logs in

Comment: So your SQL rest api is ready to authenticate? If yes, then pass the full-name to the rest endpoint ex: `https://host/ProAuth/full-name` and examine the result: if (user exist) logged him in, otherwise do the else logic...

Comment: In case your SQL rest API not ready to authenticate or register new user, you need to do that first. overall: based on your design the winforms app shouldn't include any implementation of authn, just a UI that request auth/reg from the SQL rest API.

Comment: Since you mentioned `Azure Sql`, the following link shows how to connect to Azure Sql DB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio